# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, sapui5

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)send @ sap-ui-core.js:27
sap-ui-core.js:27 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/BulletChart.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50349' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.send @ sap-ui-core.js:27
sap-ui-core.js:144 Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/m/BulletChart.js' from https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/BulletChart.js: 0 - NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/BulletChart.js'.
http://localhost:50349/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What were you trying to do? Have you got anything more relevant to share??

Comment: Besides, this is `CORS` (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) header. For more info, [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your didnt add the resource that you are trying to load in the correct path. Please check your naming and file path and make sure its correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help I made a correction

<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
  </script>

And It worked Fine..:)

Comment: @Yamini Please add the comment as an answer below and accept your the answer in order to let others know that the issue is resolved and to help future readers finding the solution quickly.